# Left outer join using LINQ - yields different outputs

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, left-join, outer-join

I am trying to write left outer join using LINQ. The SQL looks like,

```
SELECT  *                 
FROM Table1 td1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
ON td1.ColumnName = td2.ColumnName
WHERE td2.ColumnName IS NULL                  
ORDER BY SomeColumns
```

If I run this query in SQL Query analyzer, it returns say 100 records. And my converted LINQ code returns 105 records.
I have written LINQ in 2 ways as,

Method 1:

```
var data= (from td1in Table1
           join td2 in Table2.Where(a => a.ColumnName == (int?)null)
           on td1.ColumnName equals td2.ColumnName into outer
           from x in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
           orderby SomeColumns
           select td1);
```

Method 2: This gives an exception as, failed to enumerate results

```
var data = from td1 in Table1
           join td2 in Table2
           on td1.ColumnName equals td2.ColumnName into outer
           from item in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where item.ColumnName.Value == (int?)null
           orderby somecolumns
           select td1 ;
```

**The column used in where clause is nullable int type**.

The result returned in SQL analyzer seems to be correct one.
Please help me in getting the identical results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
var data = from td1 in Table1
           join td2 in Table2
           on td1.ColumnName equals td2.ColumnName into outer
           from item in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where item == null
           orderby somecolumns
           select td1 ;
```

In your original query that line `item.ColumnName.Value == (int?)null` was wrong, because you tried to retrieve value for all `ColumnName` even if `item` was null. I corrected it and now it should work fine.

Comment: it throws an exception as, 'data.ToList()' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' System.Collections.Generic.List<Table1> {System.NullReferenceException}

Comment: My mistake, fixed, try again please :)